# Identifier form is undefined

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, installation, ide, c++-cli

How can I solve the problem:

[image]

I am very new to C/C++ so I do not know what info I have to give in order to describe my problem properly. All that I was doing is trying to incorporate Windows Forms following step by step after the guy [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urhbIfR9Beo). He got everything working and I do not even though I did exactly the same stuff as he did.

Here is the code with the error:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is the first red squiggle. I mean it looks like the compiler does not know what Project1 is. With that said this is not standard c++. And my level of help will be minimal on the .net platform since I am a c++ programmer.

Comment: What you have there is known as C++ CLI. A word of advice: abandon that language.

Comment: @Ron, but I want to be able to create Windows Forms Application using C++. How can I do it the other way?

Comment: @Yaroslav you just can't. C++/CLI is **very similar** to C++, but it's **not the same**. With C++, you can't write .NET CLI code. For .NET, I'd recommend to go with C#, it's really a nice language.

Comment: @Yaroslav if what you want is a Windows GUI application in C++, there are several possibilities, you could e.g. use the old *Microsoft Foundation Classes* ([tag:mfc]) -- or try some cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit like [tag:qt].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really save yourself a lot of pain and use C# for your GUI and only use C++/CLI to wrap native unmanaged C++ code within your C# GUI.

Anyway, `Project1` is not a namespace so just drop it. Try this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Calculator instead of Project1.

Calculator::MyForm form;
Application::Run(%form)